# LeakCanary's DisplayLeakActivity has leaked, any insights?

Tags: android, leakcanary

I recently added the LeakCanary library to my application. After detecting a couple activity leaks and viewing them, I saw that LeakCanary's DisplayLeakActivity had leaked. I can't find anything in the reference path that is part of my application, and as far as I can tell, I have followed the instructions for proper usage (they're pretty straightforward :) ).

The reference path is as follows:

In com.chris:0.890:890.

- com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity has leaked:
- GC ROOT android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue
- references android.os.MessageQueue.mMessages
- references android.os.Message.callback
- references android.view.View$ScrollabilityCache.host
- references android.widget.ListView.mContext
- leaks com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity instance
- Reference Key: 48e6a173-9de4-436f-9eef-0913ebabadf6
- Device: LGE lge LG-LS980 g2_spr_us
- Android Version: 4.4.2 API: 19
- Durations: watch=5127ms, gc=246ms, heap dump=3729ms, analysis=18335ms

It should be noted that this has only occured on an LG G2. I have not seen it on any other devices. Has anyone seen this or does anyone know what might be causing it?

Comment: Clearly, you need a leak-detection library to detect leaks in your leak-detection library. :-) More seriously, since this seems to be caused by the framework, you might [follow the documentation to file an issue about this](https://github.com/square/leakcanary#my-leak-is-caused-by-the-android-sdk-implementation).

Comment: Sounds about right haha, will do.

Comment: I noticed it on my stock Nexus 5 as well.